# ssl handshake - not sure if slow

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, entropy-pool

Is there any tool that would allow me to audit or check if everything is all right concerning my SSL Handshake ?

I personally found it is a bit slow, but I really don't know if it's just me.

I am currently hosted on a VPS running OpenVZ, this is what entropy_avail looks like:

```
root@mtl:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
131
```

Do you have any idea of something else I should look into ?

Comment: How slow - and are you sure it's not other aspects of the HTTP connection?  Can you capture a request/response with something like Wireshark to see where the delay occurs?

Answer (score -1):

Run this.
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssldb/index.html

Comment: I scored 85 out of 100. Should I consider my installation as correct ? https://www.ssllabs.com/ssldb/analyze.html?d=pobourgeois.com

Comment: certainly nothing major wrong